# Subtle difference when apply `set()` to find max count items in a list

Tags: python, set, max

A friend has asked this question, and I just cannot find a good explanation for it. (He knows how the `max()` and `key` works in this case)

Given a list of scores as this:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'E']

>>> max(lst, key=lst.count)
'B'
>>> max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
'C'
# if run min - will return different results - w/ and w/o set():
>>> min(lst, key=lst.count)
'A'
>>> min(set(lst), key=lst.count)
'E'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` and `min` return the first maximal / minimal element in an iterable.

`lst.count("A")` and `lst.count("E")` are equal (evaluating to `1`), and so are `lst.count("B")` and `lst.count("C")` (evaluating to `3`). A `set` is unordered in Python, and converting a `list` to a `set` does not preserve its order. (The internal order of a `set` is [not exactly *random*, but *arbirtrary*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/382972/what-determines-the-internal-order-of-a-python-set).)

This is the reason why the results differ.

If you want to keep the order, but have unique elements, you could do:

```
unique_lst = sorted(set(lst), key=lst.index)
```

Comment: Thumb up. One question - two answers...:-) Or you can do this as well: >>> unique = list(dict.fromkeys(lst).keys())

Comment: @DanielHao Hehe, thanks. I actually updated the answer adding a link to answer the third question which might come to one's mind naturally in this context :)